# Rewrite the code in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm just learning JS and jQuery, so I can not reduce the normal code is shown below:

```
var menuBtn = '#menu',
    classMenuOpen = 'side_menu_open',

    aboutBtn = '#about',
    classAboutOpen = 'side_about_open',

    dateBtn = '#date',
    classDateOpen = 'side_date_open',

    closeBtn = '.header__menu a, .close';

// Menu Side
$(menuBtn).on('click', function() {
  $('html').toggleClass(classMenuOpen);
});
$(closeBtn).not(menuBtn).on('click', function() {
  $('html').removeClass(classMenuOpen);
});

// About Side
$(aboutBtn).on('click', function() {
  $('html').toggleClass(classAboutOpen);
});
$(closeBtn).not(aboutBtn).on('click', function() {
  $('html').removeClass(classAboutOpen);
});

// Date Side
$(dateBtn).on('click', function() {
  $('html').toggleClass(classDateOpen);
});
$(closeBtn).not(dateBtn).on('click', function() {
  $('html').removeClass(classDateOpen);
});
```

I would like to write a loop (example below) , but knowledge is not enough. I hope someone can help, thanks in advance ;)

```
['menu', 'about', 'date'].forEach((selector) => {
  $('.' + selector + ' .scrollbar-inner').scrollbar({
    onScroll: function(y, x){
      $('.' + selector + ' .scrollbar-inner').toggleClass('scroll-shadow', y.scroll >= 5);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: In the first codeblock you're using id selectors (eg `#menu`) in the second you're using class selectors (eg `.menu`). Could this be your problem?

Comment: the loop given doesn't have anything to do with your code right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
// wrap in IIFE for scope containment
(function($) {
  // Setup button keys
  const buttons = ['menu', 'about', 'date'];
  // click handler
  const createClickHandler = value => {
    // set loop variables
    let selector = `#${value}`
    ,   className = `side_${value}_open`;
    // create event triggers
    $(selector).on('click', e => $('html').toggleClass(className));
    $('.header__menu a, .close').not(selector).on('click', e => $('html').removeClass(className))
  };
  // iterate keys and apply handler method
  buttons.forEach(createClickHandler);

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the loop you are looking for!

In the `forEach()` loop you are looping through the array of strings, component holds the string element (so here `'menu'`, `'about'`, etc...). Then inside the loop's body set two variables:

1. `selector` is the selector string
2. `classOpen` is the class name of an element you have associated with the component

Then you basically write the same code using only those two variables instead of writing the code three times with set strings.

```js
let closeBtn = '.header__menu a, .close'

['menu', 'about', 'date'].forEach(function(component) {
  let selector = '#' + component;
  let classOpen = '.side_' + component + '_open';

  $(selector).on('click', function() {
    $('html').toggleClass(classOpen);
  });

  $(closeBtn).not(selector).on('click', function() {
    $('html').removeClass(selector);
  });

});
```